# where can I find the most recent version release notes of Salesforce Data Loader

Tags: data-loader, upload, upsert

I know I can download the Salesforce Data Loader directly from within Salesforce, however, how can I find out what version it is without downloading and installing it? Also, where can I find the release notes for the most recent version of Data Loader?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the [wiki page on Developerforce](https://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Loader).   There is a link to the latest [User Guide PDF](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_data_loader.pdf) on that page.

I'm not sure where to see a list of version changes in one place such as a changelog.  However, you can view the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader).  From there, you can see the [release tags](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/releases) and [issues](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Wiki can be found [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Loader). Never bothered what version I was running - not sure it really matters....